# Сколько падежей в русском языке?

Tags: грамматика

То, что в русском при желании можно насчитать несколько "нешкольных" падежей, - не новость. Но сколько именно? Тут обнаружил мнение, что их порядка 20.   https://kibernetika.livejournal.com/269196.html
При этом автор приводит всего шесть или восемь дополнительных.
Вопрос не в том, что именно считать падежами, а как считать. То есть описать по возможности все случаи согласования имен по флексиям, в которых имеются некие грамматические особенности - а уж как их объединять и что считать настоящими падежами, это уже за рамками...

На данный момент вижу максимум 18.

Основные

1. **Именительный**
2. **Родительный**
3. **Дательный**
4. **Винительный**
5. **Творительный**
6. **Предложный**

Признанные как падежные формы
7. **Партитив** (второй родительный) кусок сахару и, возможно, "отделительный" - один из нас (непонятно, разные ли это падежи.
8. **Локатив** (местный предложный) в лесу, в тени
9. **Первая счетная форма** - два час**а** (при родительном ч**а**са)
10. **Включительный/превратительный** - взять в жены
11. **Вторая счетная форма** - пять грамм (при родительном "граммов")

Не признанные в качестве отдельных форм
12. **Исходный** (он же **отправительный**, **отделительный**, **отложительный**) - **и**з лесу. *Видимо, самый сложный для индикации и дифференциации, поскольку путается и с обоими родительными, и с местным. Обычно, правда, числится как вариант второго родительного, но имеет некоторые особенности - как в позиции ударения, так и в грамматике. Более того, иногда "отделительный" и "исходный" рассматривают как **разные** падежи, отличные и друг от друга, и от партитива, и от родительного. Но тут я не вижу для того ни малейших оснований.

13. **Лишительный** - не любить мамы (при винительном "маму") - самый, пожалуй, спорный как падеж из бесспорно существующих форм.

14. **Новозвательный** - Мам!, Теть! Андрюш!

15. **Старозвательный**: Боже, Господи, человече!

16. **Беспредложный местный** - д**о**ма (единственный бесспорный пример рудиментарно сохранившегося, но исторически существовавшего падежа, ныне трактуемый как наречие).

17. **Ждательный** - ждать трамвая*  (при винительном - "ждать трамвай").
(18). **Отделительный** (партитив-2) - "один **из** нас". см. "Исходный" и "Партитив". Тут, как я понял, изрядная путаница даже в терминологии, не только в признании отдельной падежной формой.
(19). **Притяжательный** - мамин, сережин - не падеж, поскольку в русском имеет собственную парадигму форм (в отличие от английского, например).
(20). **"Направительный"** (название мое - по аналогии с тюркскими). Тоже представлен единственной рудиментарной формой "домой", но тут признать за падеж совсем уж трудно, поскольку исходная форма должна бы быть "дома", а это уже противоречит грамматике.

Итого 18 (даже если считать "отделительный" и "исходный" разными).

Где-то еще видел упоминание некоего "отличительного" падежа, но не помню, чем он знаменит, найти не могу, потому не включаю вовсе.

**Можете дополнить?**

PS. Писал экспромтом, в первой версии сильно запутался с "исходным" падежом. Пришлось вносить весьма серьезную правку. Но сейчас (вроде бы?) систематика соответствует моим представлениям.

Comment: Обнаружил еще упоминания о **временном** падеже - часом неделей (раньше), ночью, днем. Почему-то его включают в "падеж образа действия", но он сам совпадает с творительным. Путано. И еще в "первой счетной форме" можно выделить отдельную (получается, уже **"третью счетную"**) для субстантиватов - два/двое рабочих, три столовых. Пока не буду вносить в систематику.

Comment: Несколько раз думал о том, чтобі расширить список "непадежей", но отказался ибо можно совсем уже потерять границы разумного. В конце концов просто запамятовал, о каких формах думал. Но два случая мне показались достойными упоминая. Во-первых, это падеж сочетания "что за **люди, вещи** (и т д.)".

Comment: И во-вторых, очередная счетная форма. Эта форма при числительных,не имеющих множественного числа. Две листвы,детворы,бедноты. Два шашлыка. Два мороженых даже. За последнюю "счетную форму" (получается уже **четвертую**!) получил большую взбучку от маститого филолога, результат оказался прямо противоположный.   Я понял, чтоона заслуживает упоминания в моем списке. На оба случая задам отдельные вопросы.

Comment: мне микиткин видос про падежи понравился - смотрели? рекомендую https://youtu.be/4B3dxC8WY6M

Comment: @whyer посмотрел по вашей наводке видео, чего обычно не делаю. Я не знаю, что и как тут комментировать. Все, что он говрит содержательного, это то, что все современные обобые формы  не являются заимствованиями, а рождены средствами самого русского языка. Ну так это никто из серьезных авторов и не отрицает. Никто не отрицает и то, что все, кроме новозвательного, имеют очень древние исторические корни. Все остальное - если не пиар, то методологическая ошибка.

Comment: С одной стороны он рассматривает падежную структуру с подчеркнуто диахронических позиций (типа утверждения что *падеж слова "домой" исторически был дательным*) с другой на этом основании претендует, если я правильно его понял, на включение этого слова в современную систему дательного падежа, то есть занимается ревизией синхронистского подхода. Ну бред же...  Да, история современных квази-падежей не всегда прямолинейна и восходит подчас к совершенно неожиданным формам, но это не повод исключать их из рассмотрения именно как квази-падежи. По факту он напутал как минимум с одной формой - "дома".

Comment: Я совсем не уверен, что его объяснение правильное, т.е. что это остаток именно отложительного падежа, поменявшего значение (с чего бы?), но если так, то надо признать, что вместе со значением у этой формы поменялась и категория падежа. А все, видимо, потому, что признавая сложноть определения категории падежа, он не даёт свою, ту которой пользуется, отказывая отдельным формам в праве так называться.

Comment: Если мы говорим о современном русском языке, в котором "дома" и "домой" являются наречиями, то почему они причисляются к особым падежным формам [существительного]? 
Можно рассуждать об их этимологии, что само по себе интересно, но это - совсем другой вопрос.

А вообще классификация автора исходного сообщения - напомнила "Божественную комедию" театра Образцова: если есть "дательный" падеж, то должен быть и "хапательный, хватательный", а также "бдительный". :-)

Comment: @StR Вы невнимательно прочитали мой сопроводительный текст. Там есть ответы на все ваши "вопросы". А что касается вашего "почему", то это у Вас не "Божественная комедия", это обычный "Недоросль", который классифицировал "дверь" как прилагательное потому, что она приложена к своему месту.

Comment: Извините, а Вы смайлик заметили? 
А по существу моего основного вопроса (без "кавычек"), наверно имеет смысл сначала уточнить: Ваш список - _современных_ падежных форм, или за все времена существования русского языка? В то время как заглавный вопрос, хотя и неявно, предполагает настоящее время, явно это не обозначено. Так что может Вы подразумевали собрать историческую коллекцию падежей?

Comment: @StR *Извините, а Вы смайлик заметили?* Заметил.

Comment: @StR *Так что может Вы подразумевали собрать историческую коллекцию падежей?* - нет. Еще раз рекомендую прочитать текст, который вы критикуете. Лично для вас процитирую сам себя. *Вопрос не в том, что именно считать падежами, а как считать. То есть описать по возможности все случаи согласования имен по флексиям, в которых имеются некие грамматические особенности - а уж как их объединять и что считать настоящими падежами, это уже за рамками...*

Comment: *По газону* — это местный? Просто смущает предлог "по" (не похоже на *в лесу*).

Comment: @oleedd - *По газону — это местный?* - нет, это дательный. "Газон" вообще не имеет специальных форм местного.

Comment: Разве дательный может быть с предлогом? Ещё примеры: *по полю, по ветру, по столу*.

Comment: @oleedd https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/sushhestvitelnoe/predlogi-padezhey-suschestvitelnyh.html#i-4

Comment:  их только 6. Какие 18!? Вот же людям делать нечего

Comment: Не упущен ли здесь ещё один падеж: "идти полем", "идти лесом"? Разве этот падеж тождествен творительному?

Comment: @Michael_1812 *Разве этот падеж тождествен творительному?* - Не вижу причин в том сомневаться. Назовите хоть один случай "нетождественности".

Comment: @behemothus  В современном языке различий нет. Но смысловое различие огромно. Творительный падеж -- об употреблении предметов ("рыть лопатой"). Упомянутая же мною форма -- о характере и даже о направлении движения ("идти берегом", "идти речкой"). Учитывая такое отличие в смыслах, допускаю (без уверенности), что различие между этими падежами существовало, но нивелировалось.

Comment: @Michael_1812 *В современном языке различий нет.* - Спасибо. Достаточно. Обсуждение смысловых различий - это для другой темы.

Comment: @behemothus Вы невнимательно прочитали мой коммент. Разительное cмысловoе различиe свидетельствуeт о возможном различии этих падежей в прошлом. Сейчас это различие нивелировалось, но с большой вероятностью оно существовало в древнерусском.

Comment: @Michael_1812 Вероятно, это вы невнимательно прочитали мой ответ. Я повторю. ***Обсуждение смысловых различий - это для другой темы.*** И давайте заканчивать этот разговор . Хотите обсуждать семантику падежей - открывайте новую тему.

Comment: @behemothus  Как я и предполагал, эта падёжная форма действительно обладает своим бытием. Она называется "беспредложный творительный падеж" и является аналогом латинского Ablativus Loci (аблятив места). 
https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=NtUaDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6&source=bl&ots=LtyFOoEHrN&sig=ACfU3U2tMRPrBTAWgpQzIC7AnykUIgPKLg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL9fG8iI32AhX8yDgGHTwJB68Q6AF6BAg3EAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6&f=false

Comment: @behemothus Более того, некоторые специалисты разделяют творительный падеж на два родственных падежа: семантический творительный (вбирающий в себя беспредложный творительный) и синтаксический творительный. 
https://digilib.phil.muni.cz/bitstream/handle/11222.digilib/101258/A_Linguistica_08-1960-1_5.pdf

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134287/discussion-between-behemothus-and-michael-1812).