# Управление в конструкции "что за...?"

Tags: грамматика

Продолжаю тему, начатую здесь
[Сколько падежей в русском языке?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440993/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5/456795)

Какой падеж у существительного в сочетании "что за **люди**"?
Верно ли считать его вторым винительным?!

Answer (score 2):

Считаю, что это **именительный** падеж.

Второй винительный падеж (другие названия – включительный, превратительный, собирательный) встречается **после предлога "в"** при небольшом количестве глаголов, и его окончания совпадают с окончаниями именительного падежа множественного числа (другая трактовка – колебания в одушевленности (см.)): *[пойти, записаться, выбиться, готовиться, проситься, метить, принять, выбрать и т.д. в] солдаты, летчики, генералы, начальники*. **За этой формой признаются наименьшие права на статус особого падежа**.
[http://rusgram.ru/Падеж](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6)

Другое дело — *пойти в люди*, где второй винительный явно прослеживается.

Comment: Именительный с предлогом? Все чудесатее и чудесатее. В принципе-то всякое может быть, но вот предлог надо куда-то определить...

Comment: Здесь дело в том, что выделять новый падеж целесообразно тогда, когда форма слова не совпадает ни со одним из 6 падежей. Иначе падежей можно найти 100, рассматривая все предлоги, и запутаются все, даже учёные.

Comment: 1. Я не спрашиваю, когда целесообразно выделять. Я выделяю всегда, когда есть особенности в грамматике. А ученые пускай потом разбираются, падеж это, падежная форма, или что еще внутри общей падежной системы. См. связанный вопрос о падежах.

Comment: 2. Все ваши соображения никак не объясняют жизнеспособность этого урода "именительный с предлогом"  Его в русском языке не бывает. Надо пересматривать или подход к грамматике в целом (что вам, естественно никто не даст), или разбирать фразу как-то по иному. Т.е. либо считать "за" не предлогом (а частицей например), либо отказаться от самой идеи что тут именительного

Comment: Вот-вот. Хотел сказать, что "за" здесь больше похоже на частицу, но опасался вашей критики. Здесь нет никакой направленности действия. Это слово просто перетягивает вопрос на существительное с глагола: *Что за лЮди пришли? Что люди пришлИ?* Ещё такой пример: *Он восхищается проектом. Он работает над проектом.* Творительный можно тоже поделить на 2 вида - с предлогом и без. А потом можно рассмотреть функции этих предлогов и поделить ещё на 10 видов. Только зачем? Это не поможет в правописании, а лишь запутает.

Comment: @behemothus Как вам такой аргумент? *Что за люди к нам пришли?* — здесь "люди" явно подлежащее, а существительное-подлежащее может стоять только в именительном падеже.

Comment: Плохой аргумент. Все это ранее обсуждалось. Подлежащим тут в моем понимании  является не *люди*, а вся конструкция *"что за люди"*.  Попробуйте изъять из него что-либо - нарушится грамматика. Если же считать подлежащим "люди", то "что за" придется считать вопросительной частицей, а не предлогом. Но этот вариант сомнителен, больно уж замысловатая схема получается.

Comment: Другой аргумент. "За" исключительно формирует вопрос к существительному. "За люди" не может употребляться в невопросительном предложении. Разве существуют вопросительные предлоги? И ещё аргумент. Существительное после предлога всегда можно заменить местоимением (и замена отлично звучит), но не в этом случае. "За" явно больше соответствует частице.

Comment: @behemothus Падеж может быть и другим: *Вот что за людей вы пригласили! Вот что за людям вы помогаете!* Оказывается, "что за" — восклицательная частица. Как вам такой аргумент?))) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Частица_(часть_речи) http://www.slovorod.ru/russian-particles.html https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/что_за

Answer (score 2):

Здесь нет управления, ***что за*** – это частица.

Толковый словарь Кузнецова:

**Что (это) за..,** в зн. частицы. 1. (в вопросит. предл.). Обозначает вопрос о качестве, свойстве чего-л.; какой. Что это за письмо у тебя на столе? -**2. (в восклиц. предл.).** Выражает эмоциональную оценку явления (восхищение, возмущение и т.п.); ну и. Что за манера!

§ 1693. **К вопросительным частицам относятся частицы** а, ли (ль), не ... ли, неужели, никак (прост.), ужели (устар.), разве, **что за,** что, что ли, как. Все эти частицы совмещают значение вопросительности с более или менее ярко выраженной модальной окрашенностью.

Частица **что за** обычно оформляет вопрос – требование уточнения, объяснения: Что за человек?; Что это за письмо?

***Что за*** – частица, устойчивое сочетание местоимения и предлога, которое в современном языке не делится на составляющие части.

http://rusgram.narod.ru/1689-1705.html

***Что это за люди*** – какие люди, кто они и откуда.  То есть требуется уточнение, пояснение.

Можно предположить, что **исходное значение предлога ЗА** в этом неразложимом сочетании заключается в раскрытии содержания слова, обозначающего предмет (что конкретно выдается за слово *люди*, определяется словом *люди*,  как это слово расшифровывается).

Comment: Это уже лучше. Но есть одно НО. Вопросительная частица может быть союзным словом? ***Я его спросил, что они за люди***. Я, честно говоря, сомневаюсь - при всем уважении к АГ. И какой тогда падеж у слова "люди"?

Comment: Мне кажется, что частица "что за" фактически занимает в предложении позицию (неизменяемого) местоименного вопросительного слова "какой", причем во всех типах предложений. Например: Это что за люди?  Они что за люди?  Я спросил, что они за люди.  Получается: Это какие люди? Они какие люди? Я спросил, какие они люди. В этих предложениях сочетание "какие люди" занимает позицию сказуемого (форма И.п.). То есть сочетание "что за" согласуется со словом люди. Сравнить: Что за людей ты привел? Здесь уже согласование в В.п. (каких людей ты привел).

Comment: Вы ушли от ответа на прямой вопрос. В моем предложении (... спросил, что за люди...) "что за" остается частицей, но при этом становится  союзным словом? Такое вообще возможно?

Comment: Это мы видим по факту. В СПП  такого вида связь изъяснительного придаточного с главным осуществляется с помощью вопросительного слова, которое становится союзным: Я его спросил, что они за люди (кто они, какие это люди). Позицию вопросительного и союзного слова здесь занимает  частица ЧТО ЗА.  Возможно ли такое? Но частицы бывают разные, это общее  название различных структур. Нам удобно считать это сочетание частицей, потому что оно неразложимое, предлог потерял функцию управления.

Comment: Эта "частица" примыкает к словам, как обычно делают частицы, а  по смыслу она равна слову "какой", только что не склоняется, как это местоимение. Но всё это мое личное мнение, у меня нет подробной информации по теме из каких-либо источников.

Comment: То есть ответить "Да, частицам может стать союзным словом" вы не можете? В этом случае ваш дальнейший разбор теряет смысл. Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно, "мой разбор"  для Вас с самого начала не имел смысла, поэтому ещё в ответе я написала, что "могу предположить". Это как раз и означало, что источников нет, иначе бы я привела ссылку.

Comment: Дело не в источниках и не в предполоджениях. а во внутренней противоречивости подхода. Вы просто отворачиваетесь от необходимости назвать грамматическую роль синтаксически важнейшего члена. И тут никакие источники не помогут.

Comment: Если не будет внятных ответов, снимающих это противоречие,  от других авторов, я прокомментирую. подробно в своем ответе. А здесь уже движок ругается.

Comment: Спасибо, мне будет интересно узнать ваше мнение.

Comment: Получается, что "людей" согласуется с глаголом "привёл", а никак ни с "за". То же и с дательным падежом: *Вот что за людям вы помогаете!* - согласование с глаголом. При предлогах возможен лишь один падеж.