# Можно ли звательный падеж употреблять не в обращениях

Tags: падежи

Корректны ли грамматически фразы

```
Наш владыко лучше всех
Наш отче лучше всех
```

Comment: А вообще фразы корректны?

Comment: Звательный на то и звательный (чтобы звать, обращаться).

Comment: "звательный на то и звательный" - так в русском языке нет звательного падежа, эти архаизмы переросли в именительный из звательного и спокойно употребляются в позиции подлежащего. "После завтрака Владыко хотел со мной побеседовать; ", "прибыл сам владыко", "На другой день после того Владыко писал "

Comment: Нет, это звучит ужасно, здесь точно надо "а". Ещё же у имён есть: *Наш Вась лучше всех* (бред).

Comment: Не очень понятно, зачем он нужен.

Answer (score 2):

Что такое падеж? Все глаголы поделены на 5 подмножеств, в зависимости от подмножества они ставят существительное в определённый падеж (так же играет роль предлог). Так же есть падеж по умолчанию – именительный, в который ставится существительное, когда к нему не относится глагол (есть ещё один момент, как в сочетании ‟собака соседа”), а находится в роли подлежащего. Считать звательный падеж падежом – это очень кривой способ выстраивать терминологию. Во-первых, этой ‟формы” нет у большинства слов (и не было никогда, у слова ‟доктор” не было ‟формы” ‟докторе”), она есть только у имён и небольшого количества других слов. К тому же там у слов разная история возникновения этой ‟формы”: Маша – Маш – это что-то ласкательное, а отец – отче – это некие прикольные словечки, которые придумали церковники, дабы нагнать пафосу. Во-вторых, не обязательно ставить слово в ‟звательный падеж”, не обязательно говорить вместо ‟старик” – ‟старче”. Это нужно просто считать неким звательным подмножеством существительных.

А что касается использования ваших предложений, то только носителю решать, что можно использовать, а что нельзя. Какие-то грамматические правила падежей на это всё не распространяются, так как это не падеж ни разу.  Так как эти слова часто имеют пафосное значение, то можно предположить, что их могут использовать в неких комедийных целях, как в предложении: ‟Смотри, наш отче пришёл”.

Comment: Это ещё звучит, а с "владыко" не прокатит.

Comment: Если не звучит, то носитель не будет так говорить. Да, безусловно, не всё подходит.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440993